# How should I design the method signature for the following scenario

Tags: java, architecture, design-patterns

If you have a method where the input parameter might be the output.

Let's say that we have a save method that generates an autogenerated id that the client might be interested to use after the call to save().

### Person

- id (autogenerated)
- name
- ... (other fields)

Should you design the method signature like this:

1.

```
public void save(Person person);
```

The client call:

```
personService.save(person);
System.out.println(person.getId());
```

2.

```
public Person save(Person person);
```

The client call:

```
person = personService.save(person);
System.out.println(person.getId());
```

We know that in a method call that receives an object the reference to that object is passed so any changes made to the object will be perceived by others as long as they have the same reference. But in the case of remote calls serialization/deserialization occurs so my object reference is a different reference from the remote service object. So even though changes are made there the client won't notice the difference.

At this time I know that the method is not going to be a remote call so I could design it using the first signature. But what if in the future this changes and needs to be called as a remote call.

So my question is:
Should I design my API thinking that the API might be called in the future as a remote call and don't use the object parameter as a way to return a value to the client (2) or should I design my API according to my actual situation which the sevice is not remote (1)?

Thank you

Comment: Objects in Java are not passed by reference.  Everything is passed by value - it just *looks* kind of like objects are being passed by reference because the _value_ that's passed is the reference.  But there's a significant difference.  Try to write a method that swaps two object parameters.

Comment: True what I meant was that the reference passed to the service is going to be same reference if the service is in the same JVM let's say a Local EJB. But in the case of a Remote EJB the reference that points to the client object will be different and changes made to the object in the service won't be reflected on the client's object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to do both; have `save()` return the new ID *and* have a `getId()` method. Returning a value from a "setter" (a method that changes state) has lots of precedents - the java Collections API does it all the time, eg `Map.remove(Object)` returns a `boolean`.

**Fluent Interface**

There's another pattern you might want to consider, the [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) pattern. With a fluent API, you return the object (ie `this`) from every method you would otherwise return `void`. This lets the caller "chain up" method calls. With a fluent interface, your code would look like this:

```
public Person save() {
    // do your save stuff
    return this;
}
```

If you want the ID after a save, you'd code this:

```
save().getId();
```

Simple! This pattern has been used in lots of existing java code too, notably hibernate as in [this java fluent code example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java)

I would recommend using fluent, if nothing else to get the practice using it

Comment: Fluent interfaces are nice, but the underlying issue is whether the returned Person object should be the same instance as the argument.

Comment: Oops! Skimmed over that bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do both? Use the second signature, modify person locally, and for the time being, just return a reference to that same person. This way, changing it in the future for whatever needs arise won't change the API, and current users can still use your first approach.

That being said, in general, I am uncomfortable with methods that change their parameters unless that is their sole purpose and they are named and documented to indicate this. From the standpoint of "what is the method doing, and what new information do I get from it," I would probably opt for a signature like:

```
public ID save(Person);
```

Comment: This might work if the only affected attribute will be the id. But what if multiple attributes are modified. Let's say for instance creationDate of the Person a property that also was modified in that call.

Comment: Create a class that encapsulates the metadata that can be updated. Call it something like SaveData or SaveSpec. The the Person can have a field of that type, or a method that takes that type and alters its state.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the first approach since objects are seldom used in isolation. The Person object is usually referenced **by** other entities such as Employee. If you create a new instance, you're invalidating the whole object graph and believe me, you don't want to mess around with deep copying.

As for the possibility of future RPC's, whatever you'll be using to accomplish this, it will most likely be able to update the ID field after the operation commits.

@CPerkins - Objects are passed by "reference value" to be absolutely correct ;)